# Is it possible to use an enum to have access to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, data-structures, enums

Will the following work:

```
enum TileBmp {Mask, Grass, Sand, Snow, Swamp, Paved, Rock, Savannah, Lava}

ID2D1Bitmap* pBmpTile[TileBmp];
```

Will this create an array of size 9 in which any element can be accessed using either its number or its name? For exemple, would pBmpTile[3] and pBmpTile[Snow] both refer to the same ID2D1Bitmap*?

I cannot try it now and won't be capable until some times. Else I would be trying it myself.

If this won't work, are there cleaner alternatives to both

`ID2D1Bitmap* pBmpTile[9]`

and

```
ID2D1Bitmap* pBmpMask, pBmpGrass, pBmpSand, pBmpSnow, pBmpSwamp, pBmpPaved, pBmpRock, pBmpSavannah, pBmpLava;
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TileBmp` is a *type* and your array declaration is expecting a *number*, not a *type*.

This will work, since individual `enum` values **are** convertible to integers.

```
enum TileBmp {Mask, Grass, Sand, Snow, Swamp, Paved, Rock, Savannah, Lava, TILEBMP_COUNT};

ID2D1Bitmap* pBmpTile[TILEBMP_COUNT];
```

> would pBmpTile[3] and pBmpTile[Snow] both refer to the same ID2D1Bitmap*?

In this example, yes.

Unless otherwise specified, the first value in an `enum` is convertible to `0` and every other enum is `1` greater than the `enum` before it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ID2D1Bitmap* pBmpTile[TileBmp];
```

won't work. Enum name is not primary expression, can not be used as array size.

However, you can use enum fields to access array elements since enum fields are mapped to integers. For example:

```
  enum TileBmp {Mask, Grass, Sand, Snow, Swamp, Paved, Rock, Savannah, Lava};
  int A[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  std::cout << A[Sand]; //it will print 2 in this case.
```